# iTerm2, updating manually

Tags: macos, iterm

I downloaded older version of iTerm2.

```
Currently I have iTerm -> iTerm2
and
iTerm2 in /Applications/iTerm.app
```

i.e. I update iTerm. Now, I want to update iTerm2, but not through iTerm2's Check Updates function. I downloaded iTerm2 version I desire, it does state it could move it to Applications, but just want to make certain before I try. e.g. What happens to profiles, preferences, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A macOS application itself does not contain the preferences; a new version should pick up old preferences from `~/Library/Preferences`.

If you want to make a backup of the settings, you can run:

```
cp ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist.bak
```

You should then be able to just delete the old iTerm app and use the newest version. If it reads your existing settings, you're good to go. If not, then apparently newer iTerm2 versions do not support reading older iTerm data, and you have to start from scratch.